# Sticky div to top of screen when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with a Jumbotron, inside is a div 'sticky' which is positioned:absolute to the bottom. The jumbotron has a fixed height and I would like the div to 'stick' to the top of the screen when scrolled to.

I have seen multiple threads/examples on the subject but none seem to work for me (most not written in a format that works with/for Wordpress)

What is the best approach to making it work in WP (using function.php, etc)

HTML

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="sticky"><p>CURRENT WORK</p></div>
 </div>
</div><!-- /row -->
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I have a bunch of javasript brought into my WP site, I just haven't had much experience writing it on my own

Comment: I don't know WP that well, but this sounds like a case for some custom javascript. You may want to learn how to write some js and use a library like `jquery waypoints` to achieve what you want

Comment: Will the div always be at the top of the page? Or will it start further down but stick to the top when scrolling further below?

Comment: it starts a bottom of jumbotron (400px down), then sticks to the top of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, give .jumbotron a relative positioning

```
position: relative;
```

And .sticky a height value

```
height:40px;
```

You will also need to add an anchor DIV inside the sticky DIV

```
<div class="sticky"><div id="anchor"></div><p>CURRENT WORK</p></div>
```

and then the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#anchor');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.sticky').css('position', 'fixed');
          $('.sticky').css('top', '0');
          $('.sticky').css('z-index', '10000');
       } 
   });
    }
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ubLgaktp/

EDIT: you can add the javascript to the page itself by putting the following between your head tags

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#anchor');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.sticky').css('position', 'fixed');
          $('.sticky').css('top', '0');
          $('.sticky').css('z-index', '10000');
       } 
   });
    }
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

Here is a better approach. Use the anchor div to add and remove a class to the div as opposed to changing the class. This way the sticky div become 'unstuck' if the viewer scrolls back down.

Here is the jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/bh40k8Lg/

the HTML

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="sticky"><div id="anchor"></div><p>CURRENT WORK</p></div>     
 </div>
</div><!-- /row -->
```

the CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

#sticky {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
    height:40px;
}

.sticky-top {
    position:fixed!important;
    top:0!important;
    z-index:10000!important;
}
```

the Javascript which you can put between your head tags

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#anchor');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
        document.getElementById('sticky').classList.add('sticky-top');
       } else {
        document.getElementById('sticky').classList.remove('sticky-top');
       }
   });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do I put that code right in the html, or can it be put into functions.php

Comment: You can put it right into the html page. I have made an edit to the answer to reflect this. Disregard the first line, with the jquery.min.js if you are already loading a jquery file.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. It's not throwing any errors, and it's all loading correctly. It just doesn't stick at all

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer. A better solution. JSFiddle link provided. As well as necessary HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: your fiddle works, but it doesn't in my file, it scrolls right past. the line 'window.jQuery || document.write('</script>')' gets printed on the page so I don't think its being recognized as code.

Comment: perfect! I got that to work. Is it possible to write the jQuery script (first two lines) in a way that it will look for the most up to date version. I have brought in jQuery and bootstrap brought in through CDN and wordpress, to make sure the most current version is always used

Comment: From my understanding, they stopped supporting links to the "latest" version. But I could be wrong.